# awk if first field occurs multiple times comma separate second field

Tags: parsing, text, awk

I don't know if awk is the right tool here, so if I should use something else as long as it is available under unix-like systems, it's ok!

My data:

```
first foo
first bar
second foobar
third oof
third rab
```

Desired output:

```
first foo, bar
second foobar
third oof, rab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '{if ($1 in x){x[$1]=x[$1]","$2}else{x[$1]=$0}}END{for(i in x)print x[i]}' yourfile
```

**Explanation**:

The elements of array x[] are indexed by the first field of your data.

If the first field is already stored in x[], append a comma and the second field to x[]. Else, store the second field in x[].

At the end, print the contents of array x[].

Comment: Can be shortened to `awk '{x[$1]=($1 in x)?x[$1]","$2:$0}END{for(i in x)print x[i]}' yourfile`. Though it would be good to mention that due to associative nature of `awk` arrays, the output is probably going to be random.

Comment: It is true that there is no order to awk's associative arrays, and so the output may come out in any order, however no order was specified by the OP either - and this solution has the benefit that the input order does not matter either - so even repeated first fields occurring many lines apart will be collected correctly (as I perceive it). Thank you for the shorter solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '
$1==prev{line=line", "$2; next}
{if(prev) print prev,line; prev=$1;line=$2}
END{print prev,line}' file
```

#### Output:

```
$ cat file
first foo
first bar
second foobar
third oof
third rab

$ awk '
$1==prev{line=line", "$2; next}
{if(prev) print prev,line; prev=$1;line=$2}
END{print prev,line}' file
first foo, bar
second foobar
third oof, rab
```